# Plotting shapefiles with its feature using matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

Here is my question.

- A shapefile which is composed by four polygons is an example

Using:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(8,6))
ax = plt.gca()
map =   Basemap(llcrnrlon=114.3,llcrnrlat=37.95,urcrnrlon=114.75,urcrnrlat=38.2)
map.readshapefile("xxx",'xxx',zorder =1,)
patches=[]
cs=plt.cm.Blues_r(np.arange(21)/21.)
for info, shape in zip(map.xxx_info, map.xxx):
    x,y=zip(*shape)
    patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )  # facecolor= '#6582B3'
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= cs,\
                  edgecolor='none', linewidths=1.5, zorder=2,alpha = 0.8))
```

http://i13.tietuku.com/a331edcbeec29d5e.png

But when I want to depict some certain feature of these four different area(*Example: population; GDP*)

```
### for example
pop = [1000,1500,2000,500] ## corresponding to 4 polygons.
```

How to set the `facecolor` for each polygon showing the relative population size.

> In other way, the area where population was high has the darker blue as its `facecolor`, *vice versa*.

### Update

My project has 22 polygon(uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQT0xfcUd2Y0FOX0U&usp=sharing)) and the corresponding features

```
 VALUE = np.array([6152.710436, 21077.95313, 1052.05006, 2891.89123, 5717.184961,      
        2431.608241, 502.12633, 28384.79976, 0., 73919.84013, 6242.307304,     
        1072.474419, 35222.73927, 146232.4488, 4703.720773, 4080.297812,
        22897.91752, 2683.5972,   472.840926,  3367.341526,16628.64741 ,114564.1283  ])    

norm = Normalize()
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral_r')
norm = Normalize()

cs_set =pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(VALUE)))
ax.add_collection(pc)
```

http://i11.tietuku.com/256bce12e2716163.png

My question is how to add a colorbar based on the VALUE?

I tried the method in the [post](http://sensitivecities.com/so-youd-like-to-make-a-map-using-python-EN.html#.VtWhH5N94o8) I mentioned on the answer, but it doesn't work.

```
cb = colorbar_index(ncolors=len(VALUE),cmap=cmap, shrink=0.5, labels=VALUE)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)
```

http://i11.tietuku.com/fbfd19949c4ceddd.png

The colorbar label of the figure above didn't fit with the truly data?

How to fix this problem?  And is there an easier way to generate a colorbar?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out one solution. Thanks for this [post](http://sensitivecities.com/so-youd-like-to-make-a-map-using-python-EN.html#.VtWhH5N94o8)

If someone has more subtle way, please post here!

```
### original
for info, shape in zip(map.shiqu_info, map.shiqu):
    x,y=zip(*shape)
    patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )  
pc = PatchCollection(patches, edgecolor='none', \    
                     linewidths=1.5, zorder=2,alpha = 0.8) 
## don't set facecolor here

## I add four sentences here!
cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
norm = Normalize()
pop = np.array([1000,1500,2000,500])
pc.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(pop)))

ax.add_collection(pc)
```

http://i11.tietuku.com/0a07095f88ba17ab.png

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll change it!